# Tableau count number of times same value appears in column

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I have a field such that

```
Color
Pink
Blue
Pink
Blue
Pink
Pink
Pink
Pink
Pink
Blue
Blue
Pink
Pink
Pink
Blue
Pink
Blue
Pink
Blue
```

How to create calculated field to count number of times Pink appears?

Total numbers of Blue?

Comment: Why the vote to close it? I was googling this, and couldn't figure it out...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're grouping by Color and only Color in the view, then you can simply use `SUM(Number of Records)`. For example, put Color in the Rows shelf and `SUM(Number of Records)` into Text, and you'll get a table with the counts for each Color.

If you need to specify the level of detail, Tableau has [LOD (level-of-detail) expressions](https://www.tableau.com/LOD-expressions) that will make this easy.

```
{ FIXED [Color] : SUM([Number of Records]) }
```

That statement says to calculate the `SUM()` of `[Number of Records]` and to group by `[Color]`, regardless of the level of detail in the view.

---

FYI, `[Number of Records]` is a calculated field that Tableau automatically tosses into every data source. Here's the code:

```
1
```

This simply places a 1 in every row of your partition. If you `SUM()` those ones, you'll get the number of records. So your LOD calculation could have just as easily been:

```
{ FIXED [Color] : SUM(1) }
```

Comment: Hello there! Will check this shortly.